# Pass variable to EJS include

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a global header used in a couple of places and I was trying to define its location in a variable that could be passed when rendering a template.

Something like:

```
var headerLocation = 'some/location/header.ejs'; 
res.render( viewDir + '/index', {
        header: headerLocation 
    } );
```

And in a template file:

```
<% include header %>
```

header being the value passed in with the render.

It doesn't seem to be possible but maybe I missed something so thought I'd ask here.

EDIT:

This is mentioned in comments on answers below but to summarize, this is now available in version 2 of EJS.

See here: https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes
And related discussion here: https://github.com/tj/ejs/issues/93

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature has been added: if it is not path (file not found), it is evaluated as variable name. https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/pull/156

Comment: Thanks. I actually came across https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/issues/93 soon after posting this question. While there is a pull request in place it doesn't appear to have been released yet to npm. Hopefully it will get accepted and released soon. I'll mark this answer as correct once that happens so as not to mislead others who may land here. An interesting note, for whatever reason, on Windows only, using the node global object works for this. So <% include global.somepath %> somehow works. Not on Mac or Linux though. Strange one.

Comment: Think to change the bug.push line with this line (in the new code) : buf += "' + (function(){" + include + "})() + '";  (Can cause error with .push)

Comment: I just tried it, store a path in a var and tried to use the var with `include`, it still try to use the var name instead of the value. EJS `1.0.0`

Comment: https://github.com/mde/ejs#includes - so this is now available in version 2 of EJS but not version 1.

Answer (score 23):

Here is some demo code that can accomplish dynamic includes.

**View**

```
<div flex class="main-container">
    <%- include(page) %>
</div>
```

**Router**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('pages/index', {
        page: 'home'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though its an old question, answering it for others sake.

As per the github documentation, it seems EJS has no notion of blocks, only compile-time include. Since its compile time include, you need to hardcode the location.

So you are left with passing some flags and doing if checks in the header or parse the header as html and pass it to all the templates...

Answer (score 1):

Old subject, but it may help someone.

The great thing about EJS is that it is just Javascript. So something like the following should work:

```
<%
const fs = require('fs');
const content = fs.readFileSync(partial);
%>
<%- content %>
```

Hope it helps.